# how does NOLOCK works

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nolock

I know the use of NOLOCK, but can someone please help me with the mechanism of NOLOCK.

1. if a table is write-locked will no lock return values(during the write-lock).

if yes then which state of data will it refer ?

Comment: [No lock hint](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, NOLOCK can return locked data. The state of the data returned is not determined (and for almost every claim of 'it will be consistent with...' you can find a counter-example posted by one MVP or another...). NOLOCK reads are not guaranteed to be correct and, in fact, [are often incorrect](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx). There is never a good reason to use NOLOCK. You should address the underlying problem, not try to cop out with dirty reads.